# Is there any way to override the functionality of Default.aspx from within a skin?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm new to DNN and was horrified to find out that the HTML head of the site is relegated off to a file that can't really be reliably modified (Default.aspx), since upgrading DNN will overwrite any modifications.

I need to create a skin, and in order to create the skin, I need to change the doctype, add additional meta tags, link elements, a JS file, etc. all to the head. I understand that some of these changes can be made through the administration, but since they are skin specific, it seems really wrong to handle it that way. I don't want to modify Default.aspx for the reason already mentioned, and (if the first isn't bad enough) changes there affect the entire site, not just where the skin is applied.

What are my options for gaining more control of the head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ca use the [40FINGERS StyleHelper Skin Object](http://dnnskinextensions.codeplex.com/releases/view/73344) to add CSS, JS, and meta tags into the head from a skin.  I've also heard that meta tag inclusion is going to be built into a core skin object in DNN 6.1, and that the CSS and JS inclusion story will also be updated.

In addition to skin.css being automatically included ([as @skajfes mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668170/is-there-any-way-to-override-the-functionality-of-default-aspx-from-within-a-skin/7668357#7668357)), the framework also includes [skinname].css if it exists.

When all else fails, you can add a control to the head via code (add a `<script runat="server">` tag to write code in your skin):

```
private void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var link = new HtmlLink();
    link.Href = SkinPath + "example.css";
    link.Attributes["rel"] = "Stylesheet";
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
}
```

For the doctype, you can tell DNN which doctype to use for each control in your skin by adding a doctype.xml file.  See the [wiki page on setting doctypes for details](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Set-the-doctype-of-your-skin.aspx), but the basics are that you include a file named [skinname].doctype.xml, which has one XML element, `<SkinDocType>`, and you include your doctype inside of that.  The easiest way to represent the doctype in XML is to wrap is in a `CDATA` section, so you don't have to escape the angle brackets.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. 40FINGERS StyleHelper looks like just the ticket. From reviewing the documentation, it looks like it covers every use case I needed and the AddToHead attribute for arbitrary stuff is fantastic.

Comment: +1, I didn't know about 40fingers StyleHelper Skin Object. Nice.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the doctype of the skin by adding a file to your skin folder with the name [skinfile].doctype.xml, ie. if you have a skin Default.ascx you add a file in the same folder named Default.doctype.xml. In that file you set the doctype like this:

```
<SkinDocType><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">]]></SkinDocType>
```

You can link to javascript and css files using script and link tags like you would in regular html. The links are then put in the body section of the document. You can include css files in the head using the [Styles](http://www.thinkofdesign.com/blog/81/the-styles-skin-object) skin object. Note that DotNetNuke automatically includes skin.css that can be found in the skin directory.

I haven't tried adding other meta tags in the skin itself, but I've done it in modules. Here's the code I used to set meta description and keywords:

```
public void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault BasePage = Page as DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault;

    BasePage.KeyWords += "...";
    BasePage.Description = "...";

    base.Page_Load(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: +1 because I appreciate your answer. Had to give it to @bdukes, though because the skin object he recommended should help me do everything I need.

Comment: @chrisdpratt No need to explain, bdukes' answer is more usefull :) Thanks for the +1 though